# Articles (A / an / the) How do you understand difference between 'all things of that kind' and 'all the things referred to by a noun'?

Tags: grammar, articles, generic-noun-phrases

How do you understand difference between 'all things of that kind' and 'all the things referred to by a noun'?

quote:

We use **a/an** with a singular noun to say something about **all things of that kind**:
A man needs friends. (= All men need friends)
**A dog** likes to eat meat. (= All dogs like to eat meat)

We use **the definite article** to say something about **all the things referred to by a noun**:
**The wolf** is not really a dangerous animal (= Wolves are not really dangerous animals)

Comment: I don't think I'd generally say "A dog likes to eat meat"... I'd say "Dogs like to eat meat". I'd be *more* likely to say "The wolf is not really a dangerous animal" than to say the dog one... but I'd still be more likely to use "Wolves are not really dangerous animals". So, I guess what I'm saying is that, when generalizing, I tend to avoid using the singular form at all.

Comment: It's all here, in **John Lawler's [explanation about the different generic noun phrases](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever your source is for those explanations, it's wrong, or at least oversimplifying. Both of these are examples of a (rather rare) universal statement. Use of "the" in such statements is now rather old-fashioned, and would be regarded as offensive if used of humans.

Otherwise I can see no practical difference between the two. "The dog ... " refers to an archetypical dog, representing all dogs; "A dog" refers to an arbitrary, and probably typical dog, probably also representing all dogs.

By far the most common way of expressing such universals is with a plural (without "all" unless you are intending to make a wholly universal statement).

> Men need friends
>
> Dogs like meat

Comment: How about "The iPhone 7 will be groundbreaking" or "even a stopped clock tells the right time twice a day"? In these examples, the use of the plural would not be as natural in modern English.

Comment: @grateful So what would be the choice in such cases? "the" or "a" preferrable?

Comment: Definitely "the iPhone 7" in this case, @origaminal, because it's referring to the model, or the design, rather than any indiivdual phone. But "a stopped clock", because this is any (individual) stopped clock.